# How do I make "x += 5" (with x a custom class) add to a property of x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I have a class like this:

```
class C(object):
    a = 5
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.a += other
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
b = C()
b += 7
```

And have b the same, but with 7 added to b.a. However, if I actually run this, it turns b into a NoneType object. I assume this is because C.__iadd__ does not return anything.

Do I have to make C.__iadd__ return a copy of self with self.a modified? Is there a way to implement this kind of addition without copying the entire object and returning that?

Comment: "The `__iadd__()` special method is called with the value of the increment, and should return a new instance with an appropriately modified value" https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.0.html#augmented-assignment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to return `self` from the `__iadd__` method:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.a += other
    return self
```

From the [`object.__iadd__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__):

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, *self*).

Without an explicit return statement, a function returns `None` as a default, so `b += 7` produced `None` which is the result of the assignment.